# Nested git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to use a repo from git hub as submodule in my git repo.

```
git submodule add https://... (url for the repo)
```

after 1st git submodule update I get folder
My_repo_folder > first_submodule

(first_submodule directory has multiple directories)

The challenge I am facing is I want to add another repo from github inside the downloaded repo
i.e.
My_repo_folder > first_submodule > second_submodule

(I have 3 repos, one that I'm working on, 2nd and 3rd repo I am trying to pull as submodules)
Can someone please help me, if this is achievable.

1. I tried creating folder structure in advance in my working repo and then tried to add PATH in .gitmodules
   this did not work (no error is shown, however the submodules did not get updated)

2.I tried to update the PATH by editing the .gitmodules and then executing git submodule sync
No success